# How to load android google map markers faster?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Im loading markers to google map and it has really bad performace:  it takes about 5 seconds to load the map and 40 markers.(Before the map and markers load, the screen is blank)

Here's my xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The following code is adding markers to the map:

1) iterate all Restaurant objects, gets address for each restaurant.

2) converts address to LatLng objects

3) add to marker

```
      //partial of the method
      for (Restaurant rest : rests) {
            LatLng ll = getLatLng(rest.getAddress());//converts address to LatLng
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(rest.getName())
//                    .snippet("Briefly description: " + i++)
                    .position(ll)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker))
                    .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f);
            myMap.addMarker(marker);
        }


        public LatLng getLatLng(String address) {

        try {
            ArrayList<Address> addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, MAX_ADDRESS_ALLOWDED);
            for (Address add : addresses) {
                if (true) {//Controls to ensure it is right address such as country etc.
                    longitude = add.getLongitude();
                    latitude = add.getLatitude();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(myContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    }
```

Im using method `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask` for adding markers, can anyone help me?

Comment: I would suggest caching the latitude and longitude for each address after looking them up to prevent loading them every time. Geocoder requests will block and could take quite a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Also putting markers' icons in different drawable folders(hdpi,mdpi,...) instead of one folder(drawable) could be helpful. I mean making icons compatible with different screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

The onPostExecute method of a AsyncTask runs in the Main UI thread. Which is why (if you've tried) you can make a Toast from the Post execute but not from the Background thread. Basically you want to even out the load by taking some of it off of your main activity. Especially try to keep loops in the background. Use a new Thread and place the markers with a Handler.

```
public void placeMarkers(final ArrayList<String>myArray, final Handler handler){
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
        //my for loops
           for(int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++){
               //post with a handler..

               handler.post(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                        //place your markers.
                   }
               });
           }
            //etc etc.. 
        }
    }.run();
}
```

Another way would to be to use a interface between your Thread and your MainActivity thus removing the need for a handler..